# squid never_direct to certain domain and computer

Tags: proxy, squid

I need configuration squid proxy server to redirect one ip (one user) to parent proxy, also certain domain.
My configuration at now :

```
acl vkdomain dstdomain vkontakte\.ru vk\.ru vk\.com \.vk\.com
    #http_access allow 192.168.35.145 vk
    #http_access allow 192.168.35.146 vk cache_peer 192.168.32.1 parent 9999 proxy-only
 acl vkuser src 192.168.35.145 never_direct allow vkuser vkdomain
```

on 192.168.32.1 regular hardware router like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a great mess in your head. You probably need a spoon to stir it.

First of all, your understanding of squid ACL couldn't be worse. No need to escape non-regexp ACLs:

```
acl vkdomain dstdomain .vkontakte.ru
acl vkdomain dstdomain .vk.ru 
acl vkdomain dstdomain .vk.com
```

I'll skip the definition of a parent proxy - this would be your homework. After all, I just cannot configure it - you didn't provide any detail.

```
acl vkuser src 192.168.35.145/32
```

The most important part: `never_direct` should be always combined with `always_direct`.

```
always_direct deny vkdomain vkuser
always_direct allow all
never_direct allow vkdomain vkuser
never_direct deny all
```

And for God's sake, stop using user-to-IP binding, start using authentication. Bind users to their usernames instead. Your approach is insecure and easily overrideable.

Comment: Big thank you for answer! I fix it, thank you again